# QComboBox currentIndexChanged is not working properly on a QGraphicsView

Tags: c++11, qt5, qcombobox

I have a `QGraphicsView` that shows some images. On this images the user can decide to perform some operations such as i) measuring the distance between two points, ii) draw a rectangular area or iii) perform some point operations (which means that at every mouse click the user can extract x-y coordinates). 
The `QComboBox` is shown below:

[image: combobox]

The problem that I have is that everytime I try to change the operation to perform the user interface crashes. 
I am trying to figure out the reason because I specifically set the `QComboBox` to erase operations to perform everytime the user decides to change let's say from Distance to Area or from Area to Point.

For this I am using `currentIndexChanged` option available on the `QComboBox`, maybe I am not properly erasing the operations after they are performed?

See the snippet of code below:

```
bool windowingDialog::eventFilter(QPointF point)
{
    cout << point.x() << "," << point.y()<< endl;
    switch(ui->comboBoxImgA->currentIndex())
    {
        case(0): break; // this is the "select one option"

        case(1): // Popint Operation
        {
            // Move previously found point to storage
            ui->pp_ax->setText(ui->leftCoordX->text());
            ui->pp_ay->setText(ui->leftCoordY->text());
            ui->pp_az->setText(ui->leftCoordDepth->text());
            matchImages(point); // We have that, ckick and get the best match
            refreshDistance3D();
        }
        break;
        case(2): drawTwoPoints(point); break; // Click on two different points and get the distance
        case(3): refreshArea(point); break; // Draw a bounding box
    }
}

void windowingDialog::refreshArea(QPointF point)
{
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    currentPoint = point;
    drawArea(QRectF(lastPoint, currentPoint), Qt::green);
}



void windowingDialog::on_graphicsA_rubberBandChanged(const QRect &viewportRect, const QPointF &fromScenePoint, const QPointF &toScenePoint)
{
    if(viewportRect.isNull() && fromScenePoint.isNull() && toScenePoint.isNull())
    {
        {
            QRectF select;
            select.setCoords(fromScenePoint.x(), fromScenePoint.y(), toScenePoint.x(), toScenePoint.y());
            drawArea(select, Qt::green);
        }
    }
}



void windowingDialog::drawArea(QRectF area, QColor color)
{
    if(newBox != NULL)
    {
        viewerScene->removeItem(newBox);
        delete newBox;
    }
    newBox = viewerScene->addPolygon(QPolygonF() << area.topLeft() << area.topRight() << area.bottomRight() << area.bottomLeft());
    newBox->setPen(QPen(Qt::green));
    viewerScene->addItem(newBox);
    boxes.append(newBox);
    (void) color;
}

void windowingDialog::on_comboBoxImgA_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if(arg1 == "Area")
    {
        viewerScene->removeItem(pointline);
        delete pointline;
    } else if (arg1 == "Distance") {
        viewerScene->removeItem(newBox);
        delete newBox;
    } else if (arg1 == "Point") {
        viewerScene->removeItem(newBox);
        delete newBox;
        viewerScene->removeItem(pointline);
        delete pointline;
    }
}
```

Thank you for pointing in the right direction or shedding light on why this issue is happening.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to figure out on what line the program crashes?

Comment: Maybe instead of deleting and recreating the items everytime you could change the visibility with `setVisible`

Comment: @RickPat, thanks for taking the time to read my question. The error is in the `void windowingDialog::on_comboBoxImgA_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)` because the following happens:

Comment: If I click "Point", the program crashes at `viewerScene->removeItem(pointline);` and I relaunch the `gui`. If I click "Area" the program crashes at `viewerScene->removeItem(pointline);` and I relaunch the `gui`. Finally if I click "Distance" the program does not crashes until I choose "Point". I don't understand why this is happening.